# Rails WebService and C++ application to expose

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, web-services

(Sorry for my english)

First: I have an application created using C++ (this is for performance needs), this application uses an image to make some processing and returns a simple answer (1 or 0 ).

Now I need to expose this application from a webservice.

I think to create a webservice using Rails, but I don't know if it's possible using rails to call the C++ process..

The idea is to use the webservice to get an image sent by a client, pass this image to the C++ application and return (using the webservice) a message to the client, based on the result of C++ application.

Is this possible?

Any example or guideline?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: Solved using Thrift [thrift.apache.org](http://thrift.apache.org)**

---

I read something about Thrift .. but i think maybe i can't use to solve this problem (maybe) ..

The idea is use a mobile application (iOS and/or Android) where the user can upload an image to the service. The service take the image and make some image processing, this part (the processing) was written with C++ as standalone application that receive an image and return a message, so when the processing is done, the service receive the result (a message) from the processing app and return this to the mobile application.

So.. is this possible with Thrift (if so, i need to read more)? o i need to use something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't pseudotag your question titles with a status like [Solved]. If you've found the answer to your question, it's enough to mark that answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done that before, but I think you should take a look at [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) which was initially developed by Facebook and allows you to make multiple languages work together via RPC calls.

> Thrift allows you to define data types
>   and service interfaces in a simple
>   definition file. Taking that file as
>   input, the compiler generates code to
>   be used to easily build RPC clients
>   and servers that communicate
>   seamlessly across programming
>   languages.

I encourage you to search on Google with the following keywords : thrift C++ rails webservice etc.